# How to replace filter and map with filter_map?

Tags: rust

The following sample code is for finding `DIGIT_WORDS` and their first occurrence in sentence `line` ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ceb5b7e315b2900d370d2e72929b084b))

```
fn main() {
    const DIGIT_WORDS: &'static [&'static str] = &[
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
    ];

    let line = "threehpbsevenffnqgdjcftjkdjhhk7dvzmkmqthreefflb";

    let result: Vec<_> = DIGIT_WORDS
        .iter()
        .filter(|word| line.contains(*word))
        .map(|word| (word, line.find(word).unwrap()))
        .collect();
        
    println!("{:?}", result);  //output: [("three", 0), ("seven", 8)]
}
```

Not sure how could I combine the `filter` and `map` into one `filter_map`? I tried to use `filter_map` and `str::find` but the `unwrap` will fail if the word doesn't exist in the sentence.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Sorry how could the question title be more specific? Would you mind guiding me? Thanks

Comment: A better title that follows this community's standards might be something like "Print words and indices of first occurrences found in line". As Toby mentioned, the general guideline for titles in this community is that [titles "should reflect what your code does, not what concerns you have about your code"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions/2438#2438).

Comment: In any case, it's not clear that you have finished this code.  Asking for a re-write with different constraints is specifically off-topic here.

Comment: Someone told me that if I have non working code then I go to stackoverflow. If I have code improvement then I go to codereview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c460c0c607a91295bb348e97981ff9e2)):

```rust
fn main() {
    const DIGIT_WORDS: [&str; 9] = [
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
    ];

    let line = "threehpbsevenffnqgdjcftjkdjhhk7dvzmkmqthreefflb";

    let result: Vec<_> = DIGIT_WORDS
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|word| line.find(word).map(|index| (*word, index)))
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Explanation: I see that you've answered your own question and figured out that the supplied closure to [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) must return an `Option`.

A more concise way of writing what you are currently doing with the `match` keyword in your answer (morphing an `Option<usize>` into an `Option<(&str, usize)>`) is by calling [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) on the `Option<usize>` returned by [`str::find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find) and having the supplied closure to `map` return a `(&str, usize)`, as shown in the above snippet.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the filter_map can remove the None by itself and I don't need to use unwrap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I successfully replace `filter` and `map` with `filter_map`

```
let result: Vec<_> = DIGIT_WORDS
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|word| {
                match line.find(*word) {
                    Some(index) => Some((word, index)),
                    None => None
                }
            })
    .collect();
```

Just wonder if there are some solution with less line of code